# C++ std::cout buffer redirect seg fault

Tags: c++, buffer, cout

Hi So i wrote some simple code to redirect the std::cout output to a std::ostringstream and it works fine from within main eg.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(){
  std::ostringstream m_oss;
  std::streambuf *m_sbuf, *bcout;

  m_sbuf=m_oss.rdbuf();
  bcout = std::cout.rdbuf();
  std::cout.rdbuf(m_sbuf);

  std::cout<<"hello world"<<std::endl;

  std::cout.rdbuf(bcout);        // restore cout's original streambuf

  std::cout<<m_oss.str();

  return 0;
}
```

however if i want to do the same redirect within a class then I get a Seg fault
on the line 'std::cout.rdbuf(m_sbuf);'

e.g

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class test {

  public:
     std::ostringstream m_oss;
     std::streambuf *m_sbuf, *bcout;

     test(){

        m_sbuf=m_oss.rdbuf();
        bcout = std::cout.rdbuf();
        std::cout.rdbuf(m_sbuf);
     }


     void print(){

       std::cout.rdbuf(bcout);        // restore cout's original streambuf
       std::cout<<m_oss.str();

     }

};

int main(){

  test t();

  std::cout<<"Hello world"<<std::endl;

  t.print();     

  return 0;
}
```

any ideas how i can encapsulate this in a class as i don't really want the end user to see it and get confused?

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to instantiate object `t`:

```
test t;
```

not

```
test t();
```

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer. Also `test t();` is fine.

Comment: This is the correct answer, change to `test t;`. It shouldn't be in form of a question/comment though.

Comment: It is indeed the answer to my question but not the answer to my problem lol. Its late at night so i made a mistake with the simple test case i wrote for the question. (like an idiot i didnt run it first to test it even compiles). Interestingly though this test case does work but on my program where i encountered the problem it didn't. Turns out the real reason behind the seg that i was experiencing was that i have to return the cout.rdbuf() before exiting. Which in the test case i was but in my code i wasnt